# Can I move existing tags, which are currently in a global tag group, to new the new tag groups I've set up?

Tags: tags, group

I've set up new tag groups to help organise the c300b tags we have set up. How do I move the existing tags, which are already in use, to the new tag groups?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this natively in Craft through the control panel.

You could either write quick [plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that programmatically moved the existing tags to new tag groups or write some custom SQL that did it directly against the database.

For the latter, it should be as simple as updating the `groupId` column of the `craft_tags` table with the new `groupId` for the tags you want to move.